# MYSQL database insert and show data in webpage

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a form which is submitted into MySQL database after submit, it works fine.I have a field named "customer_id" which value I want to set in combination of three fields, one is "first_name", second is "last_name", and third is "id", e.g. customer_id =  (first_name+last_name+id) value (johndoe1). Id field is not in the form, this is only in database with auto increment. After setting the costumer_id value in mentioned manner, I want to display costumer_id value with success message after submit the form. Haha I want but don't know how.
How can I do this.

php code

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
//Establishing Connection with Server
$connection = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass","db");

    // Check connection
if (!$connection) {
echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
exit;
}    
if(isset($_POST['was'])){

//Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL

$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['last_name']);
$pendant_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['pendant_name']);
$desired_language = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['desired_language']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['phone']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['address']);
$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['country']);
$state = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['state']);
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['city']);
$zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['zip']);
$mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['mobile']);

$sql =  mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT into order_request(customer_id, first_name, last_name, pendant_name, desired_language,  email, phone, mobile, address, country, state, city, zip) VALUES ('$first_name$last_name', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$pendant_name', '$desired_language', '$email','$phone', '$mobile', '$address', '$country', '$state', '$city', '$zip' )");
echo '<div class="success-msg">';
echo 'data successfully submitted!';
echo '<div class="close-btn">';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        var c = document.querySelector('.close-btn');
        var e = document.querySelector('.success-msg');
        e.style.height = document.clientHeight+'px';
        c.onclick = function(){
        e.style.display = 'none';
        }
        </script>
    ";

}
 mysqli_close($connection);


?>
```

Comment: So you want to see the last insert id? (The last number / id of the auto increment column ? )

Comment: I want to make a unique customer id for every customer

Answer (score 0):

To get the id, you need to use [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php). You will get the id only if the query executes successfully and it returns the last insert id.

One more thing. Please keep your HTML and PHP codes separate. Writing HTML code within PHP echo statement is a very poor practice.

Follow this pattern:

```
<?php

 /* Other code */
 $sql =  mysqli_query(....) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
 if ($sql) {
?>
  <div class="success-msg">
     <?php echo 'Data successfully submitted!'; ?>
     <?php echo "Customer ID is : ".$first_name,$last_name.mysqli_insert_id($connection); ?>
     <div class="close-btn"></div>
  </div>
  <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    var c = document.querySelector('.close-btn');
    var e = document.querySelector('.success-msg');
    e.style.height = document.clientHeight+'px';
    c.onclick = function(){
    e.style.display = 'none';
    }
  </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks! bro 50% solution done but 50% is still remain. customer_id in the database didn't add id generated

Comment: It's supposed to be mysqli_insert_id($connection). Please see my edited answer

Comment: I already done it. echo is perfect but in database costomer_id is not combination of three fields
'first_name' 'last_name' 'id'

Comment: I don't think you need to enter that in the database. It becomes redundant. If your database has the auto increment id, first and last name, the combination can be fetched and created easily.